# WPF Border Mouse Button Click and selection ListBox item problems

Tags: wpf, events, listbox, border, selection

I have `ListBox` with a lot of items and the Border which should accomplish a task to change selected item down the `ListBox`.

For this task I try to use Border event  `MouseLeftButtonUp` (or `MouseLeftButtonDown`). The problem is when I click mouse left button the selection moves down until 2 position while I want only 1 position moving.

I debugged it step by step and this method is being executed really 2 times.

This is the code of event method:

```
    private void border1_childGrid6_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender,     
         MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        index = listBox1_childGrid5.SelectedIndex;
        index++;

        listBox1_childGrid5.SelectedIndex = index;

    }
```

`"index"` variable initialisation at the begining of class:

```
 int index = 0;
```

**Q1:** Is it a typical behavior to execute 2 times Border event method for Mouse clicking? It's strange because so far I haven't encountered such behavior of this type of events.

**Q2:** What can I do to this event be executed just 1 time or to other way to move down selection of list items 1 per 1 click???

Comment: It looks to me like there is another element inside of your Border that is not handling a click event. And that event is then propagated to your Border. Check the original source property on event args and see what is sending that event.

Comment: Inside the border there is a TextBlock

Comment: Problem has been solved. The TextBlock inside Border had the same name as Border event and this event handler was being executed 2 times after 1 click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like there is another element inside of your Border that is not handling a click event. And that event is then propagated to your Border.
Check the original source property on event args and see what is sending that event.